# Intellij Ultimate - The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">= 14.15.4". Got "12.18.3"

Tags: node.js, git, ubuntu, intellij-idea

When trying to use the git tool of my intellij, i get this error:

```
The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">= 14.15.4". Got "12.18.3"
```

I just changed my engines/nvmrc/... versions of node to upgrade it to latest lts version for this project. It seems that Intellij still tries to use the old version. Even after a complete reboot of the OS/intellij.

Any idea on how to solve it ? Thanks in advance !

Versions :

- **node** 14.15.4
- **npm** 6.14.10
- **yarn** 1.22.4
- **ubuntu** 18.04.5 LTS
- **IntelliJ IDEA** 2020.3.2 (Ultimate Edition)

nvm ls

```
       v12.18.3
->     v14.15.4
default -> 14.15.4 (-> v14.15.4)
node -> stable (-> v14.15.4) (default)
stable -> 14.15 (-> v14.15.4) (default)
```

.nvmrc

```
14.15.4
```

package.json (engines part)

```
"engines": {
  "node": ">= 14.15.4",
  "npm": ">= 6.14.8"
}
```

Comment: Do you use node for git pre-commit hooks? You might find it useful: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-23547#focus=Comments-27-4642384.0-0.

Comment: Yes I use it. Don't understand everything in your link but will try things suggested in

Comment: Ok, your solution is working. Many thanks ! Don't hesitate to add it as an answer, will mark it as answered

Answer (score -1):

package.json
engines": {
"node": "12.x"
},

for

engines": {
"node": "14.x"
},

run yarn
Voila!

Comment: It's not enough, please read this https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-23547#focus=Comments-27-4642384.0-0 as suggested by @Oksana